# Incorrect encoding used in vfpoledb.1 driver

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

I'm working on a project that needs to read/write data from/to fox pro dbf free tables. I have no problem reading or writing data as I have done so before. My problem arises, when codepage on computer is set to something different than codepage used in the tables.

The tables are encoded in windows-1250 codepage and while the computer running my exe is configured to use windows-1250, everything goes as expected. As soon as I run the program on a computer with different codepage, say windows-1252, I get weird characters.

These are my findings:

1. The `Codepage` property can be observed only in `CPCURRENT()` command, which returns whatever value is set in `Codepage`, but without any effect on the value returned.

   ```
   Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=some\path;Codepage=1250;Collating Sequence=MACHINE;Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;
   ```
2. Values returned are not converted, but simply read from the source, using incorrect encoding.

   ```
   using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
       var encoding1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
       var encoding1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
       var raw = connection.ExecuteScalar<string>("SELECT column FROM tbl0"); // returns 'éevernka' - incorrect
       var bytes = encoding1252.GetBytes(raw);
       var correct = encoding1250.GetString(bytes); // contains 'červenka' - correct
   }
   ```

Comment: Having probably exactly the same problem now. Did you find the solution? (Zdravím na Slovensko.)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing I have tried worked. The only way to get correct values is to change encoding after the data is loaded.